# oracle express sytem Invalid Login Credentials

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, ora-01017

I just installed oracle express, I'm trying to login at database homepage. trying with user sys and system with the password I gave at the installation but I cant log in.

> message: Invalid Login Credentials at SQL command line trying to
> connect ora-01017 invalid username/password; logon denied

I don't know how to modify the password or just try to uninstall and reinstall?

Answer (score 9):

You can try this from the DOS command line:

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect / as sysdba;
alter user sys identified by newpass;
```

Make sure the Oracle bin folder is on your path, but XE installation usually modifies that for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that by doing all the installation and configuration again. I have followed this tutorial: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2301639

Answer (score 0):

my friends, this problem  happend when you try connect to localhost:8080/apex/ and over linux, ubuntu or opensuse , if your answer  is yes then ,please do it .

Firts login as oracle user: 
sudo su - oracle .
then , read the next steps . 
on  http://mhananto.blogspot.com.co/2012/01/error-invalid-login-credentials-apex-40.html , all credits are to Mr Mahardika Dwi Hananto  , thanks for this amazing hack.